# NewLine in Constant Error

Tags: asp.net, path, newline

I was trying to implement this code:

```
String savePath = @"D:\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\Session Password\App_Data\file_uploads\"+uname+"\";
```

Error appears at the slash after "+uname+"
Please say why...

Comment: what error did it bring up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change it to

```
 String savePath = @"D:\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\Session Password\App_Data\file_uploads\" + uname + "\"";
```

You're just missing a closing quote at the end.

Comment: Sorry.. I typed it wrong.... My code as you said itself. But still error. What to do???

Comment: You're right.  I had it wrong, and you had it right - you were missing a quote at the end.  I edited my answer.  I plugged that line of code into Visual Studio to be sure it was right.

Answer (score 1):

Put an extra slash 
(**Escape Sequence issue**)

> String savePath = @"D:\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\Session Password\App_Data\file_uploads\" + uname + "\" ;

Answer (score 0):

if define 
string t= "C:\";
it will give you error of escape character. there we only need to add one more backward slash.
eg.
    string t= "C:\\";

it take actual string value of t is "C:\".

Comment: This explains how you might fix the same error for a similar string, but does not explain why the error occurs in the first place. Can you please elaborate about string escapes?